# would that be wrong? And if so why is it? The output is 2500

Tags: c, pointers, return-value

The output of the below code is 2500. It contains pointers. Can someone give a proper explanation of this? Why does it print as 2500? Does it come through the pointer declaration or is there another reason?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

/* Two functions include and they are operated by main function */

int *f(int x) {
    /* Creates an variable */
    int p;
    p = x;
    return &p;
}

/* Here the initialization of the function g */
int *g(int x) {
    /* Creates an variable */
    int y;
    y = x;
    return &y;
}

/* This creates two pointers called x and y */
int main() {
    int *x, *y;
    /* Here call the functions f and g */
    x = f(100);
    /* Here call the function g */
    y = g(2500);
    /* How does it print 2500? */
    /* print the value of x */
    printf("%d \n", *x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @DanLowe thanks. for that and fixing the typo, too :)

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason you are getting weird output is undefined behavior. You are returning the address of automatic local variable which will no longer exist once function reach its end.

Although, the explanation for the output can be given in terms of stack frame of function call. Since the last call is for function `g` and the argument passed to it is `2500`, the parameter `x` of function `g` is allocated on stack and `2500` is pushed to the stack. When this function return, this value popped from the stack (though the stack frame for `g` is invalid after return to the caller) and it may return this `2500` from its stack frame.

Comment: If I chanage the function call like calling f after calling the g, then the output would be 100 or another value?

Comment: It would be `100`, most probably. But, when there is UB, all bets off.

Comment: if we print printf("%d \n", *y); and then what would be the answer? any assumptions?

Comment: Result will be almost same, but do not forget that UB in action here. So, nothing can be said exactly.

Comment: x = f(100);
    /* Here call the function g */
    y = g(2500);
    /* How does it print 2500? */
    /* print the value of x */
    printf("%d \n", *x);

Comment: x = f(100);
    /* Here call the function g */
    y = g(2500);
    /* How does it print 2500? */
    /* print the value of x */
    printf("%d \n", *x);
    printf("%d \n", *y);
    return 0;

Then what would be the result?

Comment: I think you didn't get my answer. Read it carefully.

Comment: Nothing can be said exactly. But we can assume that what would be the answer. When UB is in action you have to make an assumption to get the output. Am I correct?

Comment: @ThilinaViraj; Read about [undefined behavior](http://c-faq.com/ansi/undef.html).

Answer (score 5):

In both of your functions, you try to return the address of a *local* variable in the function. Once the function finishes the execution and the control returns to the caller, the returned address becomes invalid (i.e., the variables go out of scope) and any attempt to make use of the returned value invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you have to return an address from a function and use it in the caller, you'll be needing a pointer which has been allocated memory through dynamic memory allocator  functions, like [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and family.

Comment: If I chanage the function call like calling f after calling the g, then the output would be 100 or another value?

Comment: @ThilinaViraj the problem is, once you hit the UB, nothing, absolutely nothing is guaranteed. With UB in your code, you cannot expect your code to do anything sane or meaningful.

Comment: Yes. But you can make assumptions and get the final answer. Am I correct?

Comment: @ThilinaViraj Nope, you cannot. Please read the article i linked about UB.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh: If you have to return an address from a function and use it in the caller, it is also valid to use static local variable because it is perfectly fine to do so.

Comment: @PravasiMeet yes, right. Its all about the scope, as I already mentioned.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: better If you add it into ur answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think what happens can be explained using the stack. When calling the function f, stack behaves as follows. "ret" is the return address.

```
2|   |    2|   |    2|   |    2| p |   
1|   | -> 1|   | -> 1|ret| -> 1|ret|
0|   |    0|100|    0|100|    0|100|
```

Now stack pointer is at 2, and that address (address of p) is returned and assigned to *x in main. When it returns from f, all stack values are popped, but actually what happens is just reducing the value of the stack pointer. Therefor the values pushed are still there.
The again function g is called and stack is as follows.

```
2| p  |    2| p  |    2| p  |    2| y  |
1|ret | -> 1|ret | -> 1|ret | -> 1|ret |
0|100 |    0|2500|    0|2500|    0|2500|
```

Same as function f, address of p is returned and assigned to *y in main. But notice that it's also the same address as p, 2. Hence *x and *y in main both point to the same location. Function g set the values of that address to 2500, so both *x and *y prints 2500.

Hope this helps. :)